# Graph participants configureMixer not found

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

configureMixer ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-configuremixer?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)) should be available in beta, but we get errors back saying that a resource could not be found.

Request:

```
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/calls/871f5d00-7f40-4e0c-9aad-3283e8ac1035/participants/configureMixer HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXA...tbA
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:13adf9bf-aa12-42fe-88bd-afefc67c10d7
traceparent: 00-1613065e30751243bc361f896e5de4a4-294bb2dc7c7d6946-00
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 209

{"clientContext":"whatever","participantMixerLevels":[{"exclusive":true,"participant":"80842906-de4c-4888-a66f-9aed5ba257bb","sourceLevels":[{"participant":"b42d073d-c55e-4f3b-a207-e0e95785be7c","level":0}]}]}
```

response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 15 Sep 2021 12:55:47 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
request-id: 9da6d1e6-4dc4-477d-a600-c72dadbaad0e
client-request-id: 9da6d1e6-4dc4-477d-a600-c72dadbaad0e
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"AM4PEPF0000F183"}}

{"error":{"code":"UnknownError","message":"{\"message\":\"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://pma-ukso-03.plat.skype.com:8000/newPlatform/v1/communications/calls/871f5d00-7f40-4e0c-9aad-3283e8ac1035/participants('configureMixer')'.\"}","innerError":{"date":"2021-09-15T12:55:48","request-id":"9da6d1e6-4dc4-477d-a600-c72dadbaad0e","client-request-id":"9da6d1e6-4dc4-477d-a600-c72dadbaad0e"}}}
```

I only found this [Post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/365709/why-is-participant-configuremixer-http-resource-no.html)(without answer). Anyone knows why this is returning 404??

Comment: How did you get the clientContext, could you please share the steps so that I can try it from my end.

Comment: As far as I know, the clientContext is just something that you can provide and is returned to you on the subsequent callback, so you can keep track of what belongs to what. So that seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: Is this resolved or still looking for help?

Comment: I didnt resolve it, unfortunatly. If you have some ideas...

Comment: I am also checking on it & let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Have your tried it with Graph API V1.0?

Comment: No, but I dont believe it is available in V1.0.. At least the docs don't show.

Comment: I am able to repro your issue and checking it internally. I will let you know if I find any solution for it.

Comment: I have raised a bug for it and internal team will look into it.

Comment: Is there any info/update on this?

Comment: The configureMixer in the Beta API is now deprecated.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, doesn't say so on the documentation site... Where did you get that from?

Comment: We got confirmation from engineering team. Will update doc accordingly. Thanks!